# adding operator to string return value

Tags: java, android

```
public static String convertTimeintoHrs(String hr, String mn){

        return hr + mn/60;
    }
```

mn/60 giving error - operator "/" cannot be apply to "java.lang.String","int".
How can I achieve above one instead of parsing?

Please help me on this.

Comment: you obviously can't divide strings. Only numbers. First convert your string to number. Please pass some basic Java training before you continue to avoid 1000 more such questions.

Comment: Do you want to return string or want the returned time to be int?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to parse `String` to `Integer`, because `/` java operator, and it require a valid operand to perform operation

```
public static String convertTimeintoHrs(String hr, String mn){

        return hr + Integer.parseInt(mn)/60;
}
```

For depth please read  article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String convertTimeintoHrs(String hr, String mn){
    if(hr !=null && mn !=null) {
        return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(hr) + Integer.parseInt(mn) /60);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

try this and let us know if its work

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  public static String convertTimeintoHrs(String hr, String mn){
      Float hours = Float.parseFloat(hr) + Float.parseFloat(mn)/60;
      return String.valueOf(hours);
  }
```